# Evaluate value of observable as a variable rather than a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

How do I amend `responseText: self.registrationmark` so that the value of `self.registrationmark` evaluates to a variable rather than a string?

e.g. If the value of `self.registrationmark` is `DE63BEY` then `responseText:` should evaluate to the variable `DE63BEY`

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="registrationmark" data-bind="value: registrationmark">
```

**Javascript**

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.registrationmark = ko.observable();

    var DE63BEY = { ... }
    var SL64KWX = { ... }
    var CU56OHG = { ... }
    var VN10YMY = { ... }   
    var Y926MNB = { ... }

    $.mockjax({
        url: '/test',
        dataType: 'json',
        responseTime: 2500,
        responseText: self.registrationmark
    });

    ...

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just read your comment to Matthew above, I think you first need to set the scope of the variables to this/self:

```
self.DE63BEY = { ... }
self.SL64KWX = { ... }
self.CU56OHG = { ... }
self.VN10YMY = { ... }   
self.Y926MNB = { ... }
```

Then you must be after:

```
responseText: self[self.registrationmark()]
```

ie, call

```
self.registrationmark()
```

to get a string like "DE63BEY" and then to get the corresponding variable, you need to look it up within self, as if you were doing:

```
self["DE63BEY"]
```

which is of course equivalent to

```
self.DE63BEY
```

which is the variable you're after!

Answer (score 1):

As @sifriday describes, you can define your "variables" as properties of an object, which can be looked up by name. They don't necessarily have to be defined in `self`. It can be a separate object:

```
var responses = {
    DE63BEY: { ... },
    SL64KWX: { ... },
    CU56OHG: { ... },
    VN10YMY: { ... },
    Y926MNB: { ... }
};
```

Then

```
responseText: responses[self.registrationmark()]
```

If for some reason, you need to define the values as variables, you can use `eval` to read their values dynamically. **This method is potentially unsafe and shouldn't be used.**

```
responseText: eval(self.registrationmark())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$.mockjax({
    url: '/test',
    dataType: 'json',
    responseTime: 2500,
    responseText: ko.unwrap(self.registrationmark)
});
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I don't think my question was very clear so I've elaborated it